# Exchange development good practices

Tags: blockchain, development, protocol

Is there any guide or good practice rules to follow when developing a service that uses the Bitcoin and other cryptocurrencies protocols? For instance, how is the best way to know if a user deposited coins to an address.

Comment: To enable deposits, first have a way to generate address for each user, save this to local DB , subscribe to your fullnode txnotify and blocknotify events , then once user send coins to one of his addresses your full node will notify your app on incoming tx, you can get the complete details with rpc call view the address that received the crypto , save it as waiting for confirmation and then wait for blocks to confirm.